# Chain rule (2 variable function)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the function : $$g(x,y)= f'_{x}(x,y)e^{f(x,y)-5}\sin y$$

I am trying to make a Taylor expansion and I am a little bit confused how to derive the function with respect to y. (I understand how it works with 2 functions) but when it comes to 3 I have no idea how to approach this kind of problem.

Comment: Should $f'_x(x,y)$ be $f_x(x,y)$?  $f$ is a function of two variables so $f'$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: $f'$ is the partial derivative with respect to x of the function $f(x,y)$

Comment: The partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ is denoted $f_x(x,y)$, not $f'_x(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product rule for differentiation can be generalized to three single-variable functions: 
$$
(fgh)' = f(gh)' + f'(gh) = f(g'h + gh') + f'gh = f'gh + fg'h + fgh'.
$$
For partial differentiation of the product of two-variable functions $f$, $g$, and $h$, this rule becomes $(fgh)_y = f_ygh + fg_yh + fgh_y$.